# Why VS Code automatic navigation to opened file in the side bar does not work anymore?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In VS Code versions before 1.31 when I open a file, the side bar automatically scrolls to it and highlights. This is quite useful because I have fast access to the adjacent files. However, this does not work in my current version: 1.31.1. Will this feature come back or it has been removed forever?

### Steps to reproduce

1. Open a folder with several files in VS Code.
2. Open one file.
3. Open another file.
4. Press **Ctrl + Tab**.

The first two times you press **Ctrl + Tab** automatic navigation in the side bar does not work.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to StackOverflow!  Please keep in mind that this is a forum for ***programming*** questions, not general software.  As such, I am going to flag this post as *off-topic*.  Please [visit the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [what's considered on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Have you changed "explorer.autoReveal": true in your setings?

Comment: @Tau, before acting on behalf of the community, please read the docs yourself: _software tools commonly used by programmers; and is
a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development_. While _Questions about **general** (not related to programming) computing hardware and software are off-topic_.

Comment: @Mark, no, I haven't. After reloading VS the feature works again. It seems that it fails when there are too many files opened in the tree. I'll keep watching to catch the actual moment of the problem appearance.

Comment: Updated the question with reproduction steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been fixed with `VS Code 1.32.1` release.